# Fit a square root function with basic R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I am quite new to R. I have my data already plotted and I just want to fit a nice model to it. That's it.

I think I can fit a square root model here (at least to the red data points). Or do you have another suggestion? I don't know how to do this.

My code looks like this:

```
plot(gbl$g_aH_upper~gbl$windspeed,
 main="Boundary Layer Conductance",
 ylab="Boundary Layer Conductance [m/s]",ylim=lmts, #adj=1,
 xlab="wind speed [m/s]",
 xaxt='n',
 cex.axis=0.8,
 pch=19,
 las=1,
 col="black",type="p",cex=0.7)
axis(side=1,las=1, at=c(seq(from=0,to=2.0,by=0.1), tick=F))
legend('bottomright', legend=c("Upper leaves","Lower leaves")[-50], 
   lty=1, col=c('black', 'red'), bty='n', cex=1.0, y.intersp = 0.6, x.intersp = 0.4, seg.len = 0.6,lwd=1.5, text.width = 0.8)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(gbl$g_aH_lower~gbl$windspeed, axes = FALSE, xlab = ' ', ylab = ' ', col="red" ,type="p",cex=0.7,las=1, pch=16)
```

[image: My preliminary plot with linear models]

As you can see the linear models don't fit nicely. I think I can make a better one.

Comment: The linear model seems to fit fine, as fine as a model can fit four data points. [A polynomial model will likely only do worse](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171860/how-should-we-use-the-degree-of-freedom-of-a-model).

Comment: Okay, yeah maybe you are right. But initially, my supervisor suggested using glm to fit a model there. But unfortunately, I don't understand how it works. What do you think about that?

Comment: glm, as the name implies, still fits linear models. What differentiates it from regular lm is that it doesn't assume normally distributed errors. [GLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model)

Comment: @Theresa Here is a [post on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211585/how-does-ols-regression-relate-to-generalised-linear-modelling/211592#211592) related to GLM versus OLS. Perhaps it will be helpful. This is the site for stat methodology questions if these come up in your research. Best to search for them first, since many have been asked/answered already. Also, R and Rstudio are independent pieces of software. unless your question is specifically about rstudio, then please do not add that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you all ready have a theory on the behavior of the data, that theory should be the basis of the model.  In this case y=beta0 + beta1*sqrt(x).

This model can be fitted with the standard `lm` function as opposed to the `glm` function.

Here is an example using your approximate data:

```
#create limited data
x<-c(0,  1.1, 1.4, 1.7)
y<-c(0.06, 0.115, 0.115, 0.125)

plot(y~x)
model<-lm(y~x)
#plot a linear fit
  abline(model, col="blue")
  print(summary(model))

#model with the square of x
#  I() inhibit interpretation see help(I) for more information
  modelsr<-lm(y~I(sqrt(x)))
  print(summary(modelsr))

#generate the data to the model
  xbar<-seq(0, 1.7, 0.03)
  ybar<-modelsr$coefficients[1]+sqrt(xbar)*modelsr$coefficients[2]
#plot model
lines(y=ybar, x=xbar, pch=19, col="green")
```

Yes the square root (green line) does fit the data much better than the simple linear regression(blue line):
[image]

Comment: Looks good! Thank you. 
I am trying to understand the code you wrote. Will get back to you if there are questions coming up.